# how to have hardcoded blank value of integer data type union with integer datatype column

Tags: sql, sybase

```
select id , '' as employee_id from table1
union
select id , emp_id as employee_id from table2
```

but i am getting error that incompatible datatype of employee_id from two joining union queries. so how to solve this issue.

emp_id is numeric datatype

Comment: The unioned columns must have matching data types. Either select null or 0 in the first select, or cast as varchar in the second select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want strings, then convert to strings:

```
select id , cast('' as varchar(255)) as employee_id from table1
union all
select id , cast(emp_id as varchar(255) as employee_id from table2;
```

Normally, you would use `NULL` rather than `''`, which is more compatible with more types:

```
select id , NULL as employee_id from table1
union all
select id , emp_id as employee_id from table2;
```

Note that I changed the `union` to `union all`.  `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  Only use it if you want to incur that overhead.

Comment: This is resulting in 0 being returned for table1 and not null with my JDBC calls. Any idea what is up there?